# Display whole number in report Odoo v10

Tags: floating-point, integer, report, rounding, odoo-10

There is a report "Tasks Analysis" in module "Project". It has a field "#Days to deadline". This field is displayed as "Float". Can I somehow format this field so that it is displayed as integer (rounded float)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a class that inherits from "report.project.task.user" and override field

```
delay_endings_days = fields.Integer("# Delay endings days", readonly=True)
```

Note: originally delay_endings_days was Float.